# Ignoring subdirectories in powershell

Tags: powershell, file, directory, subdirectory

I have a line of code that prints out all the files and folders with that are similar to $filename e.g. keyword "abc" will also include a file/folder "abcdef"

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\' -Filter $filename -Recurse | %{$_.FullName}
```

I'd like to have make it so that the search for these files does not go into the sub-directories of folders

e.g. a folder with name "abc" and subfolder "abcdef" only prints out "C:\abc"

Currently the line of code would print out "C:\abc" and "C:\abc\abcdef"

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried removing `-Recurse`?

Comment: @Glenn, Yes I tried and although it does remove the issue, it brings up another issue. Following on from the example above, If there is a folder "C:\test" that contains a folder named "abc" (location being C:\test\abc) it ignores this too. I'd only like to get the first instance of such a folder before it goes into it's sub-directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it.

`Get-ChildItem` is performed at the top level to populate the processing queue (`$ProcessingQueue`)

Then, a loop will run until the processing queue does not have any element left.
Each element in the queue will undergo the same process.

Either it match the filter, in which case it will be added to the `$Result` variable or it does not, in which case `Get-ChildItem` will be called on that directory and its result appended to the queue.

This ensure we do not process any further a directory tree once we have a match and that that the recursion is only applied if the directory did not match the folder in the first place.

--

```
Function Get-TopChildItem($Path, $Filter) {
        $Results = [System.Collections.Generic.List[String]]::New()
        $ProcessingQueue = [System.Collections.Queue]::new()

        ForEach ($item in (Get-ChildItem -Directory $Path)) {
            $ProcessingQueue.Enqueue($item.FullName) 
        }    

        While ($ProcessingQueue.Count -gt 0) {
                $Item = $ProcessingQueue.Dequeue()

                if ($Item -match $Filter) {
                        $Results.Add($Item) 
                }
                else {
                        ForEach ($el in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Item -Directory)) {
                                $ProcessingQueue.Enqueue($el.FullName) 
                        }
                }
        }
        return $Results
}

#Example
Get-TopChildItem -Path "C:\_\111" -Filter 'obj'
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne. I now understand the logic of it but I'm getting a few errors. Apologies if they are trivial, I'm new.


+     ForEach-Object($item in (Get-ChildItem -Directory $Path)){$Proces ...
+                          ~~
Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement.


`+     ForEach-Object($item in (Get-ChildItem -Directory $Path)){$Proces ...
+                         ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.



+ Function Get-TopChildItem($Path, $Filter) {
+                                           ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.`

Comment: Ah, oops...

`ForEach-Object` needed to be replaced by `ForEach`. I initially posted my answer using the pipeline instead but then edited without testing

I edited my answer. Try again.